# Errors in evaluation of ClassName.EnumName

Tags: java, enums, variable-assignment

I have a class say ClassX with enum defined. like so

```
public class ClassX{
    public enum XType {
        E_1, E_2, E_3, E_TC, UN_KNOWN, N_ONE;
    }
}
```

In method (methodx) in another class I am referring to the enum and assigning it to another variable like so:

```
public class AnotherClass{
    public class NestedClass {
        // some member variables
        public NestedClass(String x, CustomClass y) {
            this.m1 = x;
            this.m2 = y;
            this.b1 = false;
            this.b2 = false;
        }
    }

    public SomeType methodx() {
        XType xt = null;
        try {
            // print log stmt1
            xt = XType.E_TC;
            // print log stmt2
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            // print log stmt3
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that i get log stmt1 in log. But don't get anything after that from the methodx().

I spent hours trying to figure out what was wrong. The logs were not getting printed and nor was there any exception thrown/caught. Then, I attached debugger. Put breakpoints just before the assignment. When the breakpoint was hit, I added the XType.E_TC to the watch list.
To my surprise it said `<Errors Evaluating>`. I still went ahead with my stepping and the code jumped to constructor block of subclass block above the methodx()!

This doesn't make sense to me as the classes are correctly compiled and classes load correctly. I checked for XType by executing "javap" separately and there is no error.

Have you seen something like this before?
How to fix this?
Why does such a thing happen in the first place? I mean I can understand if the .class file of ClassX is partially built and doesn't have definition for XType, this is plausible. But the class definition and enum are correctly compiled into the .class. as mentioned above, I verified it using the javap command.

Any help and pointers are very much appreciated!

Comment: The behavior you describe is exceedingly strange.  It may be that you have one or more stale class files somewhere -- you can try to fix that by performing a full rebuild of your project.  If you want any specific help from us, however, then you'll need to post an MCVE.

Comment: John, I am pretty sure, if I make the above sample into a compilable state, I will NOT get the issue I have posted. That would be very basic Java functionality that would be broken. I need to know possible reasons and any pointers to tools or processes which might help me isolate the problem. I believe the solution would be straightforward once the root cause is identified.

Comment: Please, be more precise in your question. Be more specific. Make your question shorter as much as it can.

Comment: Bartlomiej, I believe my question is short (considering the issue at hand). I have provided relevant information and code snippet. I have asked specific questions related to the issue. no fluff. is there something I am missing here? I would like to know if anybody faced similar 'strange' behavior, I would like to know the reason why such behavior occurs and solution to it. I have done basic debugging and observed whats happening. This happening cannot be justified with basics of programming. So I am confused and want to know if I have done something wrong or setup something incorrectly.

Comment: And as John mentioned earlier, this is 'exceedingly strange'. And as he suggested I will be rechecking after rebuilding everything and confirm that no stale classes exist.

Answer (score 1):

["It may be that you have one or more stale class files somewhere"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046305/errors-in-evaluation-of-classname-enumname#comment53913750_33046305) does look like the most likely reason: your code was compiled but linked wrongly (probably, with some leftover object files) at runtime.

Explore the app's state at breakpoint hit in more details: if `XType` is loaded, from which location, how it looks, if the other entities from that compilation unit are present (add one for a test and see if it appears at runtime). Alternatively, you may do a clean build in another directory and look for differences in the runtime state.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the dependent class was not available on classpath.
I would expect ClassNotFoundException in such a case. But for reasons known to JBoss EAP6 server, it was printing this in "TRACE" level.

When I provided the correct jar file on classpath, it did not give me any error.

Am still not able to reconcile the fact that when class is not found, JBoss EAP server chose to report it in TRACE!